# Export minio-go client api using cgo, and called by C application. But the application crashed

Tags: c, go, minio, cgo

My program is written in C++, and we need to access Minio. Minio-cpp requires support for C++17, but our runtime environment only supports C++11. I wrapped the client API of minio-go into a C library to call it in our C++ program, but it results in memory errors and crashes.

The C wrapper of minio-go client is:

```
...
//export SPut
func SPut(bucketName *C.char, objectName *C.char, data unsafe.Pointer, dataLen C.long) C.long {


  // byteSlice := (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(data))[:dataLen:dataLen]
  // byteSlice := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), C.int(dataLen))
  byteSlice := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(data), int64(dataLen))
  
  fmt.Printf("put start\n")
  _, err := minioClient.PutObject(context.TODO(), C.GoString(bucketName), C.GoString(objectName), bytes.NewReader(byteSlice), int64(dataLen), minio.PutObjectOptions{})
  fmt.Printf("put done\n")

  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to write data to MinIO: %v, name = %v\n", err, objectName)
    return -1
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
...
```

In my C++ application, I call this exported function like this:

```
size_t dataLen = 10*1024*1024;
char *data = new char[10*1024*1024];
...
SPut("test-bucket", "test-data", data, dataLen);
...
```

The above code snippet is called in a thread of a C++ program. After running normally for several put operations, the program crashes. Based on the output, it can be seen that the program crashes on the line where `minioClient.PutObject` is called.

What could be the issue here?

The output of crash:

```
runtime: g28: frame.sp=0xc000073750 top=0xc0000737e0
        stack=[0xc000073000-0xc000073800
fatal error: traceback did not unwind completely

runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0x7f67fa738331?, 0x0?})
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1077 +0x5e fp=0x7f65fa7f2478 sp=0x7f65fa7f2448 pc=0x7f67fa48a17e
runtime.(*unwinder).finishInternal(0x7f65fa7f2520?)
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/traceback.go:571 +0x12a fp=0x7f65fa7f24b8 sp=0x7f65fa7f2478 pc=0x7f67fa4ad90a
runtime.(*unwinder).next(0x7f65fa7f26e0?)
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/traceback.go:452 +0x232 fp=0x7f65fa7f2530 sp=0x7f65fa7f24b8 pc=0x7f67fa4ad712
runtime.scanstack(0xc0003221a0, 0x7f67fa472054?)
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:802 +0x272 fp=0x7f65fa7f2868 sp=0x7f65fa7f2530 pc=0x7f67fa4730f2
runtime.markroot.func1()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:240 +0xb5 fp=0x7f65fa7f28b8 sp=0x7f65fa7f2868 pc=0x7f67fa471f75
runtime.markroot(0xc00003b240, 0x33, 0x1)
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:214 +0x1a8 fp=0x7f65fa7f2960 sp=0x7f65fa7f28b8 pc=0x7f67fa471c08
runtime.gcDrain(0xc00003b240, 0x3)
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:1069 +0x37d fp=0x7f65fa7f29c0 sp=0x7f65fa7f2960 pc=0x7f67fa473b5d
runtime.gcBgMarkWorker.func2()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1366 +0xa5 fp=0x7f65fa7f2a10 sp=0x7f65fa7f29c0 pc=0x7f67fa4702c5
traceback: unexpected SPWRITE function runtime.systemstack
runtime.systemstack()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:509 +0x47 fp=0x7f65fa7f2a20 sp=0x7f65fa7f2a10 pc=0x7f67fa4b9b67

goroutine 47 [GC worker (active)]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:474 +0x8 fp=0xc0002a0750 sp=0xc0002a0740 pc=0x7f67fa4b9b08
runtime.gcBgMarkWorker()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1353 +0x1f6 fp=0xc0002a07e0 sp=0xc0002a0750 pc=0x7f67fa46ff56
runtime.goexit()
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc0002a07e8 sp=0xc0002a07e0 pc=0x7f67fa4bbb01
created by runtime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers in goroutine 7
        /softs-lhaaso/tests/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1217 +0x1c
...
```

Initially, I thought it was the memory in C space (the `data` pointer) being used in Go language, and I tried three different methods to convert the C space memory to Go space:

```
  // byteSlice := (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(data))[:dataLen:dataLen]
  // byteSlice := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), C.int(dataLen))
  byteSlice := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(data), int64(dataLen))
```

However, it still didn't work.

Comment: Software versions: go1.21.3 linux/amd64, gcc 4.8.5, centos7.9, minio-go client version github.com/minio/minio-go/v7 v7.0.63